# Moving local type inference out to a struct

Tags: rust, type-inference

I have some code which works absolutely correctly when the type is defined locally and uses type inference:

but the problem is that it's loading the font in the update loop of the game. So what I'd like to do is store the `glyph` as part of the `Game` struct and let it infer the type

https://github.com/RustyRails/rustoid

and even though the Game  struct has correct type inference, the code won't compile with the error:

```
src/main.rs:89:13: 89:17 error: type mismatch resolving `<object::gfx_graphics::back_end::GfxGraphics<'_, gfx_device_gl::Resources, gfx_device_gl::command::CommandBuffer> as graphics::graphics::Graphics>::Texture == <T as graphics::character::CharacterCache>::Texture`:
 expected struct `gfx_texture::Texture`,
    found associated type [E0271]
src/main.rs:89             text(red, 32, "Hello World", &mut self.glyphs, transform, graphics)
                           ^~~~
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please produce an [MCVE](/help/mcve) and post that code here. Links to off-site resources as the primary means of understanding the problem are not appropriate for Stack Overflow, but you can include the link as further information.

Comment: @heptic can you provide a MCVE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got close.

I never used piston, but you left a tip in the comment:

```
// let glyphs =
//        &mut Glyphs::new(font, factory).unwrap() as
//        &mut character::CharacterCache< Texture = Texture<gfx_device_gl::Resources> >
//    ;
```

You are saying that `glyphs` implements `character::CharacterCache` and the associated type `Texture` must be `Texture<gfx_device_gl::Resources>`.

Adding this constraint to `on_draw` solves the problem:

```
fn on_draw<W, E>(&mut self, ren: RenderArgs, w: &mut PistonWindow<W>, e: &E)
    where W: Window, W::Event: GenericEvent, E: GenericEvent,
          T: character::CharacterCache< Texture = Texture<gfx_device_gl::Resources>>
{
    \\...
}
```

Looking at the solution, the error makes more sense:

```
<...>::Texture == <T as graphics::character::CharacterCache>::Texture
expected struct `gfx_texture::Texture`,
  found associated type [E0271]
```

the expected associated type `Texture` was a specific one (`gfx_texture::Texture` - it seems that `Texture<gfx_device_gl::Resources>` and `gfx_texture::Texture` are the same type, I tried to use `gfx_texture::Texture` direct but was unable to do so...), but `T` can have any associated type for `Texture`, not necessarily `gfx_texture::Texture`. So adding the restriction that `T::Texture = Texture<gfx_device_gl::Resources>`
solves the problem.